# how to enable both 'Website with Facebook Login' and 'Native iOS App SSO' for the same app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have the requirement that the same Facebook App should be available for authorization both via 'Website with Facebook Login' and 'SSO in Native iOS App'

Now there is a security restriction: if you enter a Site URL in your Facebook App Settings - the redirect_url you provide in the authentication dialog calls should be the same as Site URL your provided.  For SSO you have to set redirect_url to something like: fbYOUR_APP_ID://authorize... which obviously does not match my Website URL: http://test.com/... And when I do an SSO call - it gives me an error:

`"Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration."`

Is there a workaround, or did anyone encounter the situation when you need to share a single FACEBOOK APP ID for both Web and Native SSO authentication? 
Maybe the only way would be to clear the Site URL field in settings - which will remove the security restriction?